# Task returning results before getting to ContinueWith when cancelled

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

as for the title I've got some issue with a task that is returning some results to the caller before the .ContinueWith action is called in case the task get cancelled (otherwise it all works pretty well)

Following you can find the problematic code:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

WaitWindow waitWindow = new WaitWindow(ServerName, DeviceName, cts);
waitWindow.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
    {
        while(true) {
            //Do some work that returns true or false
            //and set waitWindow.ErrorMessage with a specific string
        }

    }, token).ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (antecedent.IsCanceled)
            {
                waitWindow.ErrorMessage = "Search aborted";
                waitWindow.DialogResult = false;
            }
            else
            {
                waitWindow.DialogResult = antecedent.Result;
            }
            waitWindow.Close();
        });
    });
};
waitWindow.ShowDialog();

DeserializeResult dr = new DeserializeResult((bool)waitWindow.DialogResult, waitWindow.ErrorMessage);

return dr;
```

The idea is to show a window with an indeterminate progress bar and a cancel button while the program is trying to connect to a server/device.
The possible outcomes are server/device found, timeout after a predefined amount of time e and search cancelled by the user.
The first two cases works well while the last one does not, as I wrote it gets to the "return dr" line before doing the code in the ContinueWith.

I've already tried with a wide range of combination of settings both for the task and the continuation but with no luck...

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?
If you need more info I'll be more than glad to give them.

**UPDATE**
I've notice that the first time the task is called (and cancelled) it doesn't get to the ContinueWith while the second time it does twice after going to "return dr" (both of the time antecedent.IsCanceled is false)... I absolutely don't get why...

**UPDATE 2**
Maybe it's not important but I modified my pseudo code up there to clarify that the task contains an infinite loop meant to end in one of the three cases explained above

Comment: I would guess the reason could be the Dispatcher.Invoke call. Instead of this, you can pass TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() as second parameter to the ContinueWith function. This will make the code run in the UI thread. What is cancelling your task? In case it is cancelled when the window is closed, this might be an error source, too.

Comment: I need some clarification first: a) where are you cancelling the task, I can see the token passed into it, do you check it anywhere? b) Are you waiting on that Task anywhere? ofcourse the "return dr" will get hit straight away. That's the idea right? c) Wouldn't you want to use the async/await syntax here? Yield back to the main thread but then do something after the task finishes?

Comment: @SnowballTwo Tried the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() solution but it doesn't works, still it goes to "return dr" BEFORE entering the ContinueWith.
The task is being cancelled by a cancel button on the wait window I'm opening

Comment: @Ruskin a) The task is being cancelled by a cancel button on the wait window I'm opening
b) The task is never being waited, I've tried also it but then the wait window get loaded without any elements and the program simply stalls
c) Can't use async/await, I'm working in 4.0

Comment: Maybe you have set the "IsCancel" property of your cancel button to True. This will make the view close. (Take a look in your xaml file)

Comment: @SnowballTwo The button already has IsCancel set to true. It doesn't seems usefull with the issue...

Comment: You did not understand me. Please set "IsCancel" to false!

Comment: Can you provide the code which shows how you handle the task cancellation? e.g. if( token.IsCancellationRequested ) token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

Comment: @SnowballTwo I've tried to put the exact code you cited in the task main loop but also that get always called AFTER the "return dr"...

Comment: What framework version are you using? None of this is needed in 4.5 - `async/await` means `ContinueWith` isn't necessary. Progress<T> handles progress reporting without jumping through any Invoke hooks. And support for .NET 4-4.5.1 ends in 3 weeks anyway.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm working in 4.0 so no async/await and no Progress<T>... Anyway I don't have to report any progress, I just need a window signaling that we are waiting for a long process to complete and that gives also the possibility to cancel that process...

Comment: @MatteoMeroni, have you discovered a solution to this?

Comment: Not exactly.
I still don't know why the ContinueWith is not called when i press the Cancel button since it cancels the Task too, but I found that I can simply set the DialogResult to false and a specific ErrorMessage directly in the Cancel button click handler to obtain the right behaviour.
Not exactly what I was trying to do but at least I can move on other things...